# Extjs : one digit is moving upside

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, extjs3

Using this line i set the value of label

```
Ext.getCmp('number_id').setText('<b><font size="2">'+3438+'</font></b>',false);
```

and on the UI i found it like

[image]

clearly 8 is not in same line.

Please help with reason.

Comment: This is probably not to do with js, also try not to set markup via js it seems unnecessary, also set a unit on a font size and don't use the size attribute, use a css style, in a css file

Comment: even if i remove the style, it is working in same fashion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the face and working now :

```
Ext.getCmp('number_id').setText('<b><font face="arial" size="2">'+3438+'</font></b>',false);
```

Comment: You are using deprecated html properties which aren't even supported in HTML5.. generally do not set the styling with anything other than external css, or the `style` attribute